# How to determine if a diagonal matrix exists?

Tags: matrices

I feel confused with this question.I calculated everything, the eigenvalues, eigenvectors, the inverse of P,but I cannot show that P^(-1)PA=D,I don't know what's going wrong for my solution.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't read most of what you wrote, but you have "so the eigenspace is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}"
$$

near the bottom. But $$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
 is not an eigenvector of 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is not a multiple of
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

In short: your computation of the eigenvectors -- or at least one of them -- is wrong.